# How do Zombie and Skeleton Horses spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do the Zombie and Skeleton horses spawn in Minecraft? Is there a natural way to get them, or do I have to use commands? The [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Horse) is not too clear.

If it is a command, how do I spawn a tame horse versus and untamed one?

Comment: The wiki is extremely clear:  Zombie and skeleton horses do not spawn naturally and cannot be spawned via gameplay, but can be spawned using commands when cheats are enabled, or by operators in multiplayer games.

Comment: I have readen this after the post,and I don't want to modify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 1.9, Horses can now be dangerous. If a horse has the tag `SkeletonTrap` and you come within 10 blocks of it, it turns into a skeletal horse with a skeleton riding it. The skeleton can't despawn and has an enchanted bow and enchanted iron helmet. If that were not bad enough, three others also spawn when you trigger the spawn.(FYI the skeletal horse is tamed and can be ridden with a saddle)

Comment: Just played and the ability to ride skeletal horses is bugged. IDK why

Comment: Does this happen only in dark places where skeletons usually spawn?

Comment: In 1.9 during thunderstorms, a skeleton horse can spawn as a skeleton trap. E.g. on a small island with no horses where I have a home, a skeleton horse spawned in the ocean nearby during a thunderstorm. Approaching it in a boat spawned three more skeleton horses and the skeletons.

Comment: @JonKantner, just to make it more clear: day or night, all that is needed is a thunderstorm. Poor little horse out there under the rain, I couldn't resist to approach it, fortunately managed to run from them when it was needed.

Answer (score 12):

They do not spawn naturally and aren't meant to. But you can spawn them via commands.

```
/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:[insert number],Tame:1}
```

If `Tame:1`, it is a tame horse. `Tame:0`, its not.

`Type:3` spawns a Zombie Horse, and `Type:4` spawns a Skeleton Horse.

Comment: Sorry,but I can't mark both answers.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot find Zombie or Skeleton horses in the wild.

They can only be spawned with the following commands:

**Tamed Zombie Horse:** `/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:3,Tame:1}`
**Untamed Zombie Horse:** `/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:3}`
**Tamed Skeleton Horse:** `/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:4,Tame:1}`
**Untamed Skeleton Horse:** `/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:4}`

Answer (score 2):

Skeleton horses do now spawn naturally. You will find one skeleton horse and that will summon two more leaving you with a total of three horses. Also, skeleton riding skeleton horses will spawn in thunderstorms.

Comment: What is the chance that they will spawn in thunderstorms?